# if statement not being reached

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am a beginner in python. My simple three if statements below only seems to reach the first 'if' and strangely the last 'if'. 
And what's also strange is that when I type in a number higher than 9, the high number variable won't store a number past that. I've quadruple checked the indentations. What is happening?

tldr; just trying to create a simple python script to figure out high numbers from a series of inputs and low numbers from a series of inputs. I type done when finished inputting.

```
#!usr/bin/python

number = 0 #init number variable to zero
highNum = 0 #init the highest number to 0
lowNum = 99 #init the lowest number to 99

while number != 'done':
        number = raw_input('Enter a Number: ')

        if number > highNum:
                highNum = number

        if number < lowNum:                     
                lowNum = number

        if number == "done":
                break

print "Low Number is : ", lowNum
print "High Number is: ", highNum
```

The output I get is:

```
Enter a Number: 16
lowNum :  99
highNum:  16

Enter a Number: 17
lowNum :  99
highNum:  17

Enter a Number: 9
lowNum :  99
highNum:  9

Enter a Number: 17
lowNum :  99
highNum:  9
```

Comment: lowNum = 99 is causing the reason why it is not working...

Comment: Hint: in Python 2.7, `"1" > 99` is True.

Comment: int("1") > 99 is False

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/1172714) A string is always larger than a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your input to an integer data type in order to compare it to other integers..

```
while True:
    userTyped = raw_input('Enter a Number: ')
    if userTyped == "done":
        break
    else:
        number = int(userTyped)

    if number > highNum:
        highNum = number
    if number < lowNum:                     
        lowNum = number


print "Low Number is : ", lowNum
print "High Number is: ", highNum
```

Comment: Yup, This works. I think I need to get a better idea of what "while True:" is, since I don't get while what is true...in order words, what would make it false.
Thank you.

Comment: Nothing will make it false, it will loop forever until the `userTyped == 'done'`